# Stringtemplate template arguments always evaluated to a string

Tags: antlr, stringtemplate, antlr4

I'm using Antlr 4 RC1 (the complete jar) to parse a grammar, build a custom ast, and generate code from that AST with stringtemplate4 (I use the stringtemplate classes in the antlr jar).
Inside a template I call another template with a list of beans e.g.

```
<subtemplate(myListArg=parm.listOfBeans)>
```

then inside subtemplate I get a list of Strings (each string is one of the beans evaluated to a String). But what I need is the list of java beans (e.g. simple java object with properties) because I want to process the properties of the beans and not the value of the beans, e.g.

```
<subtemplate(myListArg)> ::= <<
  <myListArg: {x | {... <x.someProperty> ...}>
>>
```

Looks to me like parameters of a template are always evaluated to strings. Is that the intended behaviour? If yes what should else should I write?

Answer (score 2):

StringTemplate 4 does not render the members of an array or `List` to strings while calling a subtemplate, as verified by the following. **Edit: Despite claims to the contrary in the comments** on this post, I reiterate that ST4 *does not* render the members of an array *or* `List` to strings while calling a subtemplate. The element types stored in the array or list make *no difference*.

```
start(class) ::= <<
<fields(class.fields)>
>>

fields(fieldsArray) ::= <<
<fieldsArray:{field | <field.name>}; separator="\n">
>>
```

If you create an instance of the `start` template and pass `Integer.class` for the `class` parameter, you get the following output:

```
MIN_VALUE
MAX_VALUE
TYPE
SIZE
```

One of the following must be occurring in your application:

1. `myListArg` is not actually a list of strings (i.e. you are getting unexpected output, but not for the reason listed here)
2. You have a `ModelAdaptor` registered for the type of `parm` which is returning a list of strings for the property `listOfBeans`
3. The type of `parm` has a `getListOfBeans` method which returns a list of strings
4. Item (3) does not hold, and the type of `parm` has a listOfBeans field which is a list of strings

Edit: Regarding the question of lists vs. arrays, I performed the unit test above with passing `new Clazz(Integer.class)` instead of just `Integer.class` to the `start` template:

```
private static class Clazz {
    private final Class<?> clazz;

    public Clazz(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public List<Field> getFields() {
        return Arrays.asList(clazz.getFields());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That helped me. class.fields has type `Field[]`. In my case myListArg is of type `java.util.List`. I converted myListArg to an array and it worked. I don't know if stringtemplate intends to handle arrays and lists as arguments differently but at least now I have a workaround. Either I will convert all lists to arrays or add an additional array field. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I found out something more. Wether a type in an array is converted to string or left as it is depends on toString() implemented by that type. So if you ever wonder why in code like this `<javabean: template()>` the parameter of template is a string try removing the toString() method of javabean.

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify that I performed this test on both arrays and the `List` interface with the same result. I also performed the test with a wrapper around the fields that implemented `toString`. I also edited the answer to clarify that the above comments are misleading and contain incorrect information.